# How to deal with Flutter release mode 0x0 error?

Tags: flutter

I am getting this error in release mode only: "The following ArgumentError was thrown during performLayout(): Invalid argument(s): 0.0".

I have done some searching and got the explanation for this error here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/5259.

Issue 5259 is resolved in this way: "We should force developers to consider those cases. Otherwise we'll have to slow down app launch to ensure that the width and height are always available at startup."

However, I am new to Flutter and I am not finding any information on how developers need to consider these cases. Do I need to get the width and height of the device before my homepage loads? Do I have to delay page loading?

I had an animation which I disabled, but the error remains, so the problem seems to arise from rendering a simple gridview.

Here is some code sample:

Main:

```
    void main() {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
      .then((_) {
    runApp(StatusStream(child: MyApp()));
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey),
        home: HomePage());
  }
}
```

Homepage:

```
    class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Easy DND'),
      ),
      body: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: 1.0,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
        children: <Widget>[
          CardOne(),
          CardTwo(),
          CardThree(),
          CardFour(),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If my answer is not enough, please provide more information and your code (minimal reproduction)

Comment: Thanks, I have now added some code. My error is here: https://pastebin.com/tdP1N1LC

Comment: Try adding `MediaQuery` to `build` in `HomePage` and return `Container()` when you get dize 0,0, and your current content otherwise. Sorry, only on the phone.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If size is `0,0` `return Container();`

You can use `MediaQuery` to get the size.